# Is it possible to replace Keycloak's build in account-console?

Tags: themes, keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-rest-api

Is it possible to connect to Keycloak an Angular 10+ spa, which gives almost the same functionality as Keycloaks Account-Console? Does anyone have experience with this?

New account console looks like "just an openid-connect"-ed reactjs webapp, i think.

Or am I better if I give up on this, and thinking in the theme functionality of account-console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New account console is shipped also with new account API (!= admin REST API), so nothing stopping you to build own independent SPA (in your favorite platform: Angular, React, Vue, ...), which will utilize that account API.

See (random) blog post about that: https://www.marcus-povey.co.uk/2020/10/12/using-the-keycloak-accounts-management-api/